# JS Problems in Wordpress (myinit is not defined)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have this errors in Wordpress:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: myinit is not defined at
>   HTMLScriptElement.onload

I can see with inspect several added code to javascripts like:

```
   ..../scripts.js' async onload='myinit()'></script>
```

or

```
....tools.min.js' async onload='myinit()' defer='defer'></script>
```

I have deleted the cache plug-in but this is not a solution.
When I first open the site in incognito mode, some hover effects and slider revolution don't work, but after I make several refreshes, it looks perfect (even if I have still the errors)

Is there any way to delete all the `onload='myinit()'`?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution.

I deleted this part in **functions.php** at theme directory.

```
function defer_parsing_of_js ( $url ) {
    if ( FALSE === strpos( $url, '.js' ) ) return $url;
    if ( strpos( $url, 'jquery.js' ) ) return $url;
    return "$url' async onload='myinit()";
}
add_filter( 'clean_url', 'defer_parsing_of_js', 11, 1 );
```

I don't now why it got there.